# Flex property binded to datagrid dataProivder array

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have the following datagrid in my application mxml:

```
<event:SelectRowDataGrid id="resultDG" 
    dataProvider="{model.EventDTOs}"
    ...
    <event:columns>
        ...
```

SelectRowDataGrid is my extension of the Flex DataGrid:

```
package xx.xx.xx.xx.event
{
import mx.controls.DataGrid;

public class SelectRowDataGrid extends DataGrid 
{
    private var _checkedItems:Array;

    public function SelectRowDataGrid() {
        super();
        _checkedItems = new Array();
    }

    public function get checkedItems():Array
    {
        for each (var event:EventDTO in dataProvider) {
            if(event.checked)
                _checkedItems.push(event);  
        }
        return _checkedItems;
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to set the enabled property of a button like so:

```
<controls:PrintButton enabled="{resultDG.checkedItems.length>0}"
```

But I get the followin error when building:

> Multiple markers at this line:
>   -Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "length".
>   -checkedItems

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing bindable metatag http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7fff.html http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by Timofei Davydik

Adding [Bindable] annotation to the class made it happen:

```
[Bindable]
public class SelectRowDataGrid extends DataGrid 
{
...
```